# Racket of Hu Yun

Tags: equipment, badminton, racket

### Hu Yun

Lately Hu Yun has gotten my attention with his performance in the below mentioned tournaments. He plays with a white Yonex racket.

Does anybody know the type of racket he plays with?

### References

1. [BWF Profile Hu Yun (BWF)](http://bwfcontent.tournamentsoftware.com/profile/overview.aspx?id=37B8D414-634F-4C3F-93AC-91C7399EF113)
2. [OUE Singapore Open 2015](https://youtu.be/HoN92YzUubI)
3. [Yonex Japan Open 2014](https://youtu.be/DYkqISePM04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Yonex](http://www.yonexusa.com/company/news/badminton/lee-chong-wei-crowned-his-fifth-yonex-open-japan-title/) page, he has played with the [NANORAY 750](http://www.yonex.com/sports/badminton/products/badminton/racquets/nanoray-series/nanoray-750/), but seeing as how he lost the match, I don't know whether he still does.